# common lisp: how to suppress newline or "soft return"

Tags: common-lisp

This code

```
 (defun arabic_to_roman (filename)
     (let ((arab_roman_dp '())
           (arab nil)
           (roman nil))

       (with-open-file (in filename
                           :direction :input
                           :if-does-not-exist nil)

         (when in
           (loop for line = (read-line in nil)
              while line do
                (setq arab (subseq line 0 (search "=" line)))
                (setq roman (subseq line (1+ (search "=" line)) (length line)))
                (setf arab_roman_dp (acons arab roman arab_roman_dp))
                                           ;(format t "~S ~S~%" arab roman)
                )))

       (with-open-file (stream #p"ar_out.txt"
                               :direction :output
                               :if-exists :overwrite
                               :if-does-not-exist :create )
         (write arab_roman_dp :stream stream :escape nil :readably nil))
       'done!))
```

seems to work well. It takes a file with entries like this

```
1=I
2=II
...
```

and builds one large list of dotted pairs. However when I look at the output file, it seems as though soft returns or newlines have been inserted.

```
((4999 . MMMMCMXCIX) (4998 . MMMMCMXCVIII) (4997 . MMMMCMXCVII)
 (4996 . MMMMCMXCVI) (4995 . MMMMCMXCV) (4994 . MMMMCMXCIV)
 (4993 . MMMMCMXCIII) (4992 . MMMMCMXCII) (4991 . MMMMCMXCI) (4990 . MMMMCMXC)
...
```

I was expecting the output to look more like just one continuous line:

```
((4999 . MMMMCMXCIX) (4998 . MMMMCMXCVIII) (4997 . MMMMCMXCVII) (4996 .  MMMCMXCVI) (4995 . MMMMCMXCV) (4994 . MMMMCMXCIV) (4993 . MMMMCMXCIII) (4992 . MMMMCMXCII) (4991 . MMMMCMXCI) (4990 . MMMMCMXC) ...
```

Is my code the way it is indeed throwing in newlines somehow? I've used the `write` version of `princ` which supposedly suppresses newlines. Later I want to read this file back into the program as just one big list, so I don't want newline issues.

Comment: If you use the Lisp reader to read it back, newlines are not an issue, anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the pretty-printer is being invoked (the default is implementation-dependent), to print it with indentation and human-readable line lengths. Use `:pretty nil` to disable this.

```
(write arab_roman_dp :stream stream :escape nil :readably nil :pretty nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

A better way to write it:

- use functions to create blocks of code, which can be combined
- less side effects and fewer variables
- no need to test for `in`
- easy to understand control flow

Example:

```
(defun arabic_to_roman (filename)
  (flet ((read-it ()
           (with-open-file (in filename
                               :direction :input
                               :if-does-not-exist nil)
             (loop for line = (read-line in nil)
                   for pos = (position #\= line)
                   while line collect (cons (subseq line 0 pos)
                                            (subseq line (1+ pos))))))
         (write-it (list)
           (with-open-file (stream #p"ar_out.txt"
                                   :direction :output
                                   :if-exists :overwrite
                                   :if-does-not-exist :create)
             (write list :stream stream :escape nil :readably nil :pretty nil))))
    (write-it (read-it))
    'done-read-write))
```